# Not needing index.php from example.com/{lang}/index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

My .htaccess currently looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^/]+)/\?lang=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/?$ $2/?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which means that `example.com/{lang}/some-page.php` acts as `example.com/some-page.php?lang={lang}`

Remaining issue: `example.com/{lang}` does not work unless it has `index.php` like `example.com/{lang}/index.php

How can I make it work when we go directly to `example.com/{lang}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_rewritten} !=1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-z]{2})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /%1/$1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})(?:/([^/]+))?$ $2?lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA,E=rewritten:1]
```

I really don't like matching on THE_REQUEST so changed that. This also redirects just `/?lang=xx` which you may not want. I used the same matching for lang strings in both rules which you may not want. Let me know.

Not sure you need the file or directory existence checks and it is slowing things down a bit if not necessary, as the filesystem must be polled twice on every request. Do you have two letter files or directories in root?

Comment: Don't have 2-letters files/directories so we can omit. Using your rules however when I go to `example.com/xx`, I get a 404

Comment: I removed the checks. Are you putting it in root .htaccess file?

Comment: I added checks to avoid a loop.

Comment: Yes - it's the root .htaccess file. Now I get an internal server error when going to any url

Comment: Sorry there was a typo, fixed now.

Comment: `example.com/xx` now works! But new problem: the assets (css, js etc.) are 404'ed

Comment: What directory are they in? They're probably just being referenced with relative URLs. Use absolute URLs as they think they're in a subdirectory now.

Comment: /css/{file}.css /js/{file}.js

Comment: You said you didn't have two letter directories :) will add an exception for that

Comment: Ahhh my bad haha. `js` is the only 2-letters one

Comment: I added an exception for '/js/'.

Comment: You probably still need to use absolute URLs to reference them though, if css not working.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it :)

Comment: Just reviewing this and that first `RewriteCond` wasn't needed, so can be removed to shorten the rules a bit. I removed it in the answer.

Comment: Great. Also, could there be something messing up the cookies with this? I set a cookie for example on `example.com/fr/blabla.php` to `fr` but then when going to `example.com`, that cookie was not updated (holds an older value)

Comment: Nothing in this could be affecting that directly. But perhaps you are setting your cookie to only be valid within '/fr/'?

Comment: I am setting it up like `setcookie('lang', 'fr', strtotime('+1 year'));`

Comment: Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php, you need to set the path to '/' or it will only be valid in the directory it was set in and beneath.